# Finding records where an ancestor has a column set to a certain value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Rails 3.2
```

In my models/ticket.rb, I have:

```
belongs_to :ticket_profile
```

And in my models/ticket_profile.rb, I have:

```
has_many :tickets
attr_accessible :ticket_id
```

In my ticket_profile model, I have:

```
attr_accessible :type
```

How can I do a search, for tickets, where the ticket_profile type is a specific values, for example: "flowers".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where`

```
TicketProfile.where(:type => 'flowers').tickets
```